# What is the difference between NullableContextOptions and NullableReferenceTypes?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've been playing with new `c# 8.0` `NullableReferenceTypes` feature for a while.
And I'm little bit confused about turning this feature on via changing `.csproj` file.

I mean in order to enable this feature you have to put the following lines in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But also I've found another one way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So it almost the same but anyway. What is the difference between `NullableContextOptions` and `NullableReferenceTypes`?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9517) may help you.

Comment: Since VS 16.1 the property was renamed to Nullable. Neither NullableContextOptions nor NullableReferenceTypes are valid any more. The name is shorter and aligns with the command line argument.

Answer (score 8):

In earlier previews, the compiler only allowed two settings (true/false, meaning on/off).

In later previews (starting with preview 2), the compiler allowed more options, so the name of the setting and the possible options were changed.

Here's the documentation of the possible options and their meanings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Note that the property name is now simply `<Nullable>`.

Answer (score 4):

As of .NET Conf 2019 (C# 8.0 release), the correct way to achieve default non-nullable reference types is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have Visual Studio 2019 preview 2, or .NET Core 3.0 preview 2 in order to use `NullableReferenceTypes`.

You also need to enable C# 8.0. Check the `LangVersion` element to make sure its set to `8.0`.

`NullableReferenceTypes` is changed to `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>` in Visual Studio 2019 preview 2

PS: this feature does not yet work in **.Net Framework**

Comment: what do you mean this feature does not yet work in .net framework ? I can use the following line to enable this feature for my .net framework app: `#nullable enable`. And it actually works well. But I have no idea how to enable it via `.csproj` file.

Comment: there is an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9517#issuecomment-466805405)

Comment: basically I created it yesterday )

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu What do you mean "this feature does not yet work in .Net Framework" ? It works fine for me.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu it works only with new csproj format, otherwise `<NullableContextOptions>` is ignored.